# facebook : load the wall content of a facebook page in a website

Tags: facebook, fbml, xfbml

I have a website and a facebook page for the website. For most of the news update, I post them on the facebook page's wall.

Now I want to show the wall's content of that facebook page on my website, just like the facebook's Like Box with "stream" enabled: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

However, I only want to show the stream, and perfectly can show it in my own presentation. So is it possible to get only the content of a facebook page by facebook's API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you use the SDK you can get it by using

```
fb->api("/{id}/feed");
```

There's a php and a javascript sdk.

But you also need an access token now to get the feed of a page.

**EDIT:** Here's a copy of example.php (from the php-sdk) modified for your purpose.

```
include_once("facebook-sdk/facebook.php");

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'APP_ID GOES HERE',
  'secret' => 'SECRET GOES HERE',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.

    // This is where we grab the posts
    $wall_posts = $facebook->api('/courseyou/posts');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
?>


<?php if ($user): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
<?php else: ?>
<div><a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a></div>
<?php endif ?>

<h3>Wall Posts</h3>
<?php
foreach ($wall_posts["data"] as $post) {
    echo "<p>".$post["from"]["name"].": ".$post["message"]."</p>";
}
?>
```

As far as I know you need an access token to view a page's posts/feed with the api, which makes me think that you need the user to login with facebook.... I'm fairly new to this, but you should look into how to get an access token, because you need one for this.

Comment: could you provide a more detailed code example? for example, I would like to load the posts of this wall: http://www.facebook.com/courseyou either in PHP or js is ok, as long as I can get the news feed of this page. (only the feed posted by the page owner, not by its fans)

Comment: Just so you know, you don't have to use a users access token to get access to /YOUR_PAGE_ID/feed. You can simply use your app id and app secret, just put them together with a | (pipe) in between them eg: YOUR_APP_ID|YOUR_APP_SECRET